# How can I do Model.find(:except => 'desc') in rails 2.3.x?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, alias

The following is a great way to make accessing the database faster by only 'selecting' specified columns on a table:

```
Article.find(:all, :select => 'name')
```

This will find all of the articles and only return the name. Even if it has a `body` attribute it will complain about it being an undefined attribute because of select.

How would you do `:select => 'name'` but the reverse; meaning that I want to select everything but the specific column, e.g. ':except =>'. I want to be able to do this:

```
Article.find(:all, :except => 'body')
```

Let me know if this doesn't make sense.

Comment: I never did that before, maybe you could loop all columns and select everything but the column you pass as an argument?

Comment: That part is just self.columns - `:except` I'm just not that sure about the other parts.

Comment: You could do this :

`Article.find(:all, :select => (Article.columns - ['body']))`

Comment: Wow, thanks so much. I'm specifically trying to send a and `:except =>` option though.

Comment: I can see that, but since that isn't there you could use what I mentioned above, I think it's concise enough, but if not that, even in your extension you could use the similar logic instead of the lengthy .map call.

Comment: Your completely right. I did get the `:except =>` working though :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def find_with_except(*args)
  options = args.extract_options!
  raise "Find accepts select or except but not both." if options[:except] && options[:select]
  if options[:except]
    formated_options = Array(options.delete(:except)).map!(&:to_s)
    options[:select] = (Article.column_names - formated_options).join(", ")
    find_without_except(*(args << options))
  else
    find_without_except(*(args << options))
  end
end
alias_method_chain :find, :except
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
Model.find(:all, :except => 'body')
```